# My icons in the homescreen are not showing up (galaxy s6 edge)

Tags: stock-android, crashes, performance, home-screen-shortcuts, samsung-galaxy-s-6

I have a Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge and I bought it about 2-3 weeks ago. Its performance has been weakened lately, first snapchat stopped working and every time I open it crashes. And now none of app icons are showing in the home

[image: Screenshot_Homescreen]

<sub>Homescreen - Click to enlarge image</sub>

Comment: I wish I could post a pic of my app menu here so you could see what the problem looks like

Comment: Well @Arshan you can always edit you question by clicking the edit button. You can either upload a screenshot image or give us a link of the image added to your question description.

Comment: Click [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/posts/111934/edit) to edit your question and click the icon of image to upload the image. (see cursor location in [this pic](http://i.stack.imgur.com/mo5ML.png) to know the location of icon.)

Comment: Nvm I restarted my phone and the icons are showing

Comment: thank you @Lucky, I'm kinda new to this website. I'm not deleting this question just in case someone else might find it useful. (it's really silly though :D )

Comment: @ArshanKhanifar Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. You can add your own answer if you solved your problem and accept it later. So that reader will find it easily in the answers section instead of comments.

Answer (score -1):

Restarted my phone and its all good now